# ¿Por qué no está funcionando word-wrap: break-word; para la información recogida en una celda de datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**03/10/2016 09:00. Primero pensé que no funcionaba sWidth:**

He tenido que añadir a un datatable 5 campos más, con los nombres solo todos encajan a la perfección en el body. Mi problema viene cuando cargo los datos, ya que uno de los campos contienen información muy extensa y hace que dicho campo se alargue demasiado y esto a su vez que dicha tabla sobresalga del body haciendo que la visualización de la página sea muy fea.

Como verán a continuación **tengo la propiedad autowidth a false y asignadas unas anchuras para intentar que no ocurra el problema que les menciono**. Copio el código:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var oTableTSC;
var index;

$(document).ready(function(){                               
    $("#tabs").tabs();  

    oTableTSC = $('#tablaMT').dataTable({
                                                "bJQueryUI": false,
                                                "bAutoWidth": false,
                                                "bLengthChange": false,
                                                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                                                "bFilter":false,
                                                "bPaginate": false,
                                                "bInfo": false,
                                                "bSort": false,
                                                "aoColumns": [  
                                                { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "12%", "sClass": "center" },
                                                { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "9%", "sClass": "center" },
                                                { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "15%", "sClass": "center" },
                                                { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "9%", "sClass": "center" },
                                                { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "15%", "sClass": "center" },
                                                { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "30%", "sClass": "center" },
                                                { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "3%", "sClass": "center" },
                                                { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "7%", "sClass": "center" }]     
    }); 
    pintarTablaMT();
});
```

He probado a copiar en la página de estilos css con llamada al id de la table, del datatable y algo más que no recuerdo ***word-wrap: break-word;*** y asignarle también un ancho para que no salga del contenedor donde está la tabla y no funciona. He mirado en modo depuración de los navegadores si coge dichos cambios y los coge pero no funcionan ya que sigue visualizándose mal y no se que probar más.

También he probado en la parte de html a darle anchura de todos los tipos, por px, %, em, y no sufre ningún cambio, a las tablas padre, a sus contenedores, a que todos tuviese la misma unidad de tamaño, etc.

**03/10/2016 12:30.**
*Continuo probando cosas, he mirado los datos de un objeto los cuales aparecen vacíos para esta tabla y las columnas cogen el ancho del nombre de cada columna, lo que me lleva a deducir que el fallo puede ser que no esté funcionando la propiedad **bAutoWidth: false** no creen? Que puedo hacer para que funcione?*

**03/10/2016 13:30.** *Le he dado un ancho a la tabla y al mismo tiempo he utilizado **table-layout: fixed;** y lo que es la tabla en sí me queda ajustada al contenedor, sin embargo un campo con información muy extensa me sigue sobresaliendo hasta por fuera de dicho contenedor. Esto lo he probado gracias a la información aportada por @blonfu pero lo que me sigue sin funcionar y podría darme la solución es ***word-wrap: break-word;*** ¿Alguien sabe a que se puede deber?*

Si alguno tiene alguna idea con la que poder ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Comment: Prueba con `table-layout: fixed`. Un ejemplo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj5dqxsw/2/)

Comment: Gracias, eso me funciona, pero el contenido me sigue sobresaliendo, no queda introducido dentro de la tabla, como si el word-wrap: break-word; no funcionase. @blonfu

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un jsfiddle con tu tabla?

Comment: No puedo @blonfu es una aplicación muy grande y recojo datos a través de formulario y las tablas o contenedores padres vienen de otros archivos diferentes. Estoy jugando con lo que me has dicho y la tabla en sí queda bien con los tamaños que le estoy proporcionando pero la que tiene la información extensa sigue sobresaliendo y no encaja en la celda...

Comment: Pues es  raro  ya que  `word-wrap: break-word;` corta las palabras hasta dejarlas en una letra por fila si es necesario como puedes ver en el ejemplo. A lo mejor hay otros estilos que entran en conflicto

Comment: ya ya, si te iba a decir eso, que la tabla en si está como tu la has puesto en el ejemplo solo que los datos los recibe como te he explicado y que los estilos los coge de la librería de jquery... A mí también me parece raro, si consigo averiguar algo te lo comunico. Gracias y un saludo, te voy diciendo. @blonfu

Comment: @blonfu ya me han dado con la solución, espero que te ayude si alguna vez manejas algo relacionado y no lo sabías. Gracias también por tus respuestas, me han ayudado a darle una mejor visualización a la tabla :)

Comment: Vale, he visto la solución, por eso te pedía tu código, tenía que haber algún estilo en conflicto, en mi ejemplo no estaba usando la clase `nowrap` y por eso funcionaba bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He probado a copiar en la página de estilos css con llamada al id de la table, del datatable y algo más que no recuerdo word-wrap: break-word; y asignarle también un ancho para que no salga del contenedor donde está la tabla y no funciona

Si miras el ejemplo principal de la página de [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), verás que por defecto la tabla tiene una clase `nowrap` que afecta tanto los `th` como los `td` con la regla:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Esta es la razón por la que no puedes romper el texto aunque agreges `word-wrap: break`. La solución es **sobreescribir** dicha regla en tus estilos:

```
table td {
  white-space: normal !important;
  word-wrap: break;
}
```

Comment: Fantástico, muchísimas gracias. Era concretamente eso. Me has ayudado muchísimo. Espero que le pueda servir a alguien más en el futuro. :)

Comment: Seguramente sí ;)

Comment: @MitsuGami Bien visto:), también se puede eliminar directamente la clase `nowrap` en lugar de sobreescribirla, por optimizar un poco (eliminarla de la tabla no del CSS)